# Gifted chat message hidden by input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

[image]everything is fine but when I try to type the last message will be hidden and it is happening on the Android device as shown in the image

this is my code

```
     export function Chat() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMessages(initialMessages.reverse());
  }, []);

  const onSend = (newMessages = []) => {
    setMessages((prevMessages) => GiftedChat.append(prevMessages, newMessages));
  };

  return (
    <GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      text={text}
      onInputTextChanged={setText}
      onSend={onSend}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
        name: 'Aaron',
        avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/150/150/any',
      }}
      alignTop
      alwaysShowSend
      scrollToBottom
      // showUserAvatar
      renderAvatarOnTop
      renderUsernameOnMessage
      bottomOffset={26}
      onPressAvatar={console.log}
      renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
      renderActions={renderActions}
      renderComposer={renderComposer}
      renderSend={renderSend}
      renderAvatar={renderAvatar}
      renderBubble={renderBubble}
      renderMessage={renderMessage}
      renderMessageText={renderMessageText}
      renderCustomView={renderCustomView}
      isCustomViewBottom
      forceGetKeyboardHeight={false}
      messagesContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      parsePatterns={(linkStyle) => [
        {
          pattern: /#(\w+)/,
          style: linkStyle,
          onPress: (tag) => console.log(`Pressed on hashtag: ${tag}`),
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

this is how i setup but the hidding is  the only problem
[image]

everything is fine but when I try to type the last message will be hidden and it is happening on the Android device as shown in the image

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat#notes-for-android

Specifically: Append KeyboardAvoidingView after GiftedChat. This should only be done for Android, as KeyboardAvoidingView may conflict with the iOS keyboard avoidance already built into GiftedChat, e.g.:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <GiftedChat />
   {
      Platform.OS === 'android' && <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" />
   }
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<GiftedChat
    {...props}
    renderChatFooter={()=><View style={{height:<some value>}} />}
    />
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)